# Wordpress tinyMCE Keep Wrapping <p> Tags To HTML Codes When Saving

Tags: tags, tinymce, customization

Wordpress tinyMCE keep adding `<p>` tags when I saved my custom post types in visual mode opened!

I had searching for many solutions, but not working. Here is the solution that I found, but this is unable to stop wordpress from adding annoying `<p>` tags from my html codes:

**Javascript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     tinyMCE.init({force_p_newlines : false});
</script>
```

**PHP**

```
function tinymce_remove_root_block_tag( $init ) {
    $init['wpautop'] = false; 
    $init['force_p_newlines'] = false; 
    $init['forced_root_block'] = false; 
    return $init;
}
add_filter( 'tiny_mce_before_init', 'tinymce_remove_root_block_tag' );
```

I don't want any kind of solution which is using `the_content` hook, because this is still letting `<p>` tags inside wordpress text editor. Example:

```
remove_filter ("the_content", "wpautop");
```

What else should I use to stop tinyMCE from messing up html codes with its auto added `<p>` tags?

Answer (score 0):

I use this on my instals to get rid of p tags around images:

```
/*
*
* Remove annoying <p> tags on images, messes with my shizzle
*
*/


function my_filter_ptags_on_images($content)
{
    return preg_replace('/<p>(\s*)(<img .* \/>)(\s*)<\/p>/iU', '\2', $content);
}

add_filter('the_content', 'my_filter_ptags_on_images');
```